# Apache POI HWPF - Output a table to Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi

I've been Googling for quite awhile and haven't found a definitive answer.  Is it possible to output a table using Apache POI?  It looks like it hasn't been implemented, since the main developer stopped working on it like 5 years ago.

Is there an open source alternative to POI that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're right in that Apache POI is dead in the water. Clearly it wasn't glamourous enough.

The only alternative that I'm aware of is [iText](http://itextdocs.lowagie.com/tutorial/rtf/index.php), which can generate RTF documents, which MS Word (and every other similar application) can read. It includes full table support.

And, of course, iText can generate PDF also.

Answer (score 0):

If docx and java are both ok for you, try [docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org)